# How do I get 1 address for each distinct name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have [the following SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58d53/1):

```
CREATE TABLE tester(
  name TEXT,
  address TEXT
  updated DATE
 )
```

Each name can have more than 1 address. e.g. Bob can have an address in NYC and LA. Mary can live in Paris and Chicago. I would like to get distinct names and then return an addresses of theirs that hasn't been updated for 1 day (it doesn't matter which address...just as long as it hasn't been updated). I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name) name, address FROM tester WHERE updated < (NOW() - interval '1 day') 
  HAVING count(address) > 1;
```

I get:

```
column "tester.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: use the group by function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `distinct on`, you need an `order by`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, address
FROM tester
WHERE updated < (NOW() - interval '1 day') 
ORDER BY name;
```

However, that doesn't get the ones with more than one address.  For that, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, MAX(address)
FROM tester
WHERE updated < (NOW() - interval '1 day') 
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: `MAX(address)` made me smile :)

Comment: Oh and `To use distinct on, you need a group by` should read `To use distinct on, you need an ORDER BY`